# Microsoft Speech in .net core 3.0

Tags: wpf, .net-core, microsoft-speech-platform

I've used Microsoft Speech previously (not sure which version it was) with `.net framework` and it did work. I don't have that project on my PC now. I've downloaded and installed the [Runtime 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225) and [SDK 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226) and referenced the `.dll` in my `.net core 3.0` project from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Assembly\Microsoft.Speech.dll`. Here's what I've now in my ViewModel:

```
.
.
.
using Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Read
{
    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth;
        string inputText;
        public string InputText { get => inputText; set { inputText = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public Command Speak { get; set; }
        public Command Pause { get; set; }
        public Command Resume { get; set; }
        public Command Stop { get; set; }

        public VM()
        {
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            synth.Volume = 75;
            Speak = new Command(speak, (o) => synth.State != SynthesizerState.Speaking);
            Pause = new Command(pause, (o) => synth.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking);
            Resume = new Command(resume, (o) => synth.State == SynthesizerState.Paused);
            Stop = new Command(stop, (o) => synth.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking || synth.State == SynthesizerState.Paused);
        }

        void speak(object obj) => synth.SpeakAsync(InputText);
        void pause(object obj) => synth.Pause();
        void resume(object obj) => synth.Resume();
        void stop(object obj) => synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();

        #region Notify Property Changed Members
    }

    public class Command : ICommand ...
}
```

and in xaml, I've these:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding InputText}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 5"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Content="Speak" Command="{Binding Speak}"/>
            <Button Content="Pause" Command="{Binding Pause}"/>
            <Button Content="Resume" Command="{Binding Resume}"/>
            <Button Content="Stop" Command="{Binding Stop}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I think that's all I'd in my previous Text2Speech. Now with all these, in my .net core project, it isn't working!

Comment: [Windows-only] System.Speech is now available for .NET Standard 2.0 onwards via official nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Speech/5.0.0 as well as compatibility pack https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11 is not compatible with .NET Core.

[Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) is the new .NET Standard compliant API that is available for .NET Core.

You'll find a [quickstart](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/csharp/dotnetcore/from-microphone) on GitHub. The official docs is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/#pivot=start&panel=speechtotext).

Comment: looks like it's a must to be online and have an azure a/c to use that! The same code doesn't work with .net framework now! It does work with `framework` if I use `System.Speech.Synthesis` instead!