# How to use Windows System.Speech for TTS in PowerShell 7 (or is there an alternative)

Tags: windows, powershell, text-to-speech, powershell-core

I have the same profile.ps1 in both WindowsPowerShell and PowerShell.
It includes commands that invoke Windows Text-To-Speech
However, these commands fail when run in PowerShell 7.

The errors occur when I try to use the $PomrptTTS object I create with the following code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$PromptTTS = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
```

In PowerShell 7, any attempt to access or use my $PormptTTS object, produces the following:

```
SetValueInvocationException: ....\profile.ps1:82
Line |
  82 |  $PromptTTS.Rate = 0 ; $PromptTTS.Speak("Time for the $((Get-Date).DayofWeek) shuffle")
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception setting "Rate": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

MethodInvocationException: ....\profile.ps1:82
Line |
  82 |  … e = 0 ; $PromptTTS.Speak("Time for the $((Get-Date).DayofWeek) shuffle")
     |                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Speak" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159159/microsoft-speech-in-net-core-3-0#comment118630314_59159159

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of PowerShell 7.0 / .NET Core 3.1, [`System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer) is [considered a **.NET Framework-only API**](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34441#issuecomment-613714938) and therefore not supported in .NET Core.

- A discussion about this is ongoing in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34963); since the underlying API is *specific to Windows*, the question is whether it's worth exposing via the *cross-platform* .NET Core framework.

The **workaround** is to use the [`SAPI.SpVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v%3Dvs.85)) COM object (which the .NET Framework API is ultimately based on, I presume):

```
$sp = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SpVoice
$sp.Speak("Time for the $((Get-Date).DayOfWeek) shuffle")
```

---

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442080/windows-10-powershell-how-to-change-the-voice-used-for-sapi-spvoice) asks about *changing the speaking voice*, which, unfortunately doesn't seem to be supported in PowerShell Core as of PowerShell 7.0, due to limited COM support - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446733/45375).

Comment: Many thanks, @mklement0
I find this works for both "Desktop" and "Core" versions of PowerShell.
I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: [Windows 10 PowerShell - How to change the voice used for SAPI.SPVoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442080/windows-10-powershell-how-to-change-the-voice-used-for-sapi-spvoice)

Answer (score 1):

mklement0's answer is better, but if you want a slightly hacky Windows 10+ option that works with version 7 (but not version 5) you can use the [Windows Media Foundation speech api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=winrt-18362) instead.

[Here's a gist that uses this option](https://gist.github.com/lselden/ab2e04fbac785e0644c4b562bf5e35cd).

The nice thing about using the Windows Media Foundation is you can use [all of the "OneCore" voices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22805/windows-10-supported-narrator-languages-voices) that are supported in Windows Narrator, whereas SAPI only supports the three default voices

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for sharing. It actually does seem to work in Windows PowerShell (v5.1).