# How to change the voice used for SAPI.SPVoice

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, sapi

I would like to be able to select an alternative voice for my Text-To-Speech output.
I am using the ComObject SAPI.SPVoice but I am finding that I cannot change the actual voice used.
(BTW - I am using SAPI.SPVoice because it works in both PowerShell Core and PowerShell Desktop on Windows 10)

```
${PromptTTS} = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVoice
```

```
❯ $PromptTTS | gm
```

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{269316d8-57bd-11d2-9eee-00c04f797396}

Name                                   MemberType   Definition
----                                   ----------   ----------
DisplayUI                              Method       void DisplayUI (int hWndParent, string Title, string TypeOfUI, Variant ExtraData)
GetAudioOutputs                        Method       ISpeechObjectTokens GetAudioOutputs (string RequiredAttributes, string OptionalAttributes)
GetVoices                              Method       ISpeechObjectTokens GetVoices (string RequiredAttributes, string OptionalAttributes)
IsUISupported                          Method       bool IsUISupported (string TypeOfUI, Variant ExtraData)
Pause                                  Method       void Pause ()
Resume                                 Method       void Resume ()
Skip                                   Method       int Skip (string Type, int NumItems)
Speak                                  Method       int Speak (string Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags)
SpeakCompleteEvent                     Method       int SpeakCompleteEvent ()
SpeakStream                            Method       int SpeakStream (ISpeechBaseStream Stream, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags)
WaitUntilDone                          Method       bool WaitUntilDone (int msTimeout)
AlertBoundary                          Property     SpeechVoiceEvents AlertBoundary () {get} {set}
AllowAudioOutputFormatChangesOnNextSet Property     bool AllowAudioOutputFormatChangesOnNextSet () {get} {set}
AudioOutput                            Property     ISpeechObjectToken AudioOutput () {get} {set by ref}
AudioOutputStream                      Property     ISpeechBaseStream AudioOutputStream () {get} {set by ref}
EventInterests                         Property     SpeechVoiceEvents EventInterests () {get} {set}
Priority                               Property     SpeechVoicePriority Priority () {get} {set}
Rate                                   Property     int Rate () {get} {set}
Status                                 Property     ISpeechVoiceStatus Status () {get}
SynchronousSpeakTimeout                Property     int SynchronousSpeakTimeout () {get} {set}
Voice                                  Property     ISpeechObjectToken Voice () {get} {set by ref}
Volume                                 Property     int Volume () {get} {set}
queryMSDNClassInfo                     ScriptMethod System.Object queryMSDNClassInfo();
```

My research indicates that I should be able to:

```
❯ $PromptTTS.Voice = ${PromptTTS}.GetVoices().Item(0) ; $PromptTTS.Speak("Hello voice 0")
❯ $PromptTTS.Voice = ${PromptTTS}.GetVoices().Item(1) ; $PromptTTS.Speak("Hello voice 1")
❯ $PromptTTS.Voice = ${PromptTTS}.GetVoices().Item(2) ; $PromptTTS.Speak("Hello voice 2")
```

and so on.

However, whilst the commands execute without error, the voice used /heard does not change.

Comment: Works on my machine, Win10 1909, I get Hazel (female), David (male), Zira (different female). Can you show us the output from `$PromptTTS.GetVoices()`?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen -- is this working in PowerShell Core?

Comment: This works on PowerShell 7.2.1 on Windows 11. Just tried and it played all 3 voices.

Comment: You can always change default text to speech voice in windows control panel, look for 'text to speak' in start menu

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, ***assigning to* `.Voice` in order to *change the speaking voice* does *not* work in PowerShell *Core*, as of v7.1.0-preview.2** - it only works in *Windows PowerShell* (PowerShell versions up to v5.1).

.NET Core's COM support is limited, and while PowerShell (Core) in part compensates for that, there are things that still do not work.

In effect, the following assignment is *quietly ignored* in PowerShell (Core) 6+:

```
# !! IGNORED in PowerShell [Core] 6+ - the default voice (David)
# !! is NOT changed (to Hedda).
$PromptTTS.Voice = $PromptTTS.GetVoices().Item(1)
```

Personally, I do not know of a workaround (at least with PowerShell code alone).

---

**Technical background**:

Inspecting the `.Voice` property with `$PromptTTS | Get-Member Voice` yields:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{269316d8-57bd-11d2-9eee-00c04f797396}

Name  MemberType Definition                                    
----  ---------- ----------                                    
Voice Property   ISpeechObjectToken Voice () {get} {set by ref}
```

I *suspect* that the `set by ref` part is the problem, which *may* be related to the following problem, quoted [from this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11837#issuecomment-585971165):

> the `ComBinder` is not supported in .NET Core (the call `ComInterop.ComBinder.TryBindSetMember` in PowerShell Core [is a stub method](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a578347b5a9d4b7c48f2cd303f876dfa6f27cdce/src/System.Management.Automation/CoreCLR/CorePsStub.cs#L190)).

Comment: mklement0 - I just did this on my Win10 PSv5x/PSv7 both work as expected.

Comment: @postanote: That it works in Windows PowerShell (up to v5.1) is to be expected; in PowerShell (Core) 7.0 (and the latest preview) it does _not_ work - _the voice isn't changed_ - at least on my Windows 10 Pro (64-bit; Version 1909, OS Build: 18363.778) machine; but, to be clear: I don't think the problem is related to the specific Windows 10 version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I tried and it seems to work just fine on PowerShell 7.1

```
Param (
    [switch] $Male,
    [switch] $Female,
    $Text = "Please input a text in double quotes"
 )
if ($Female)
  {$voice = 1}
else
  {$voice = 0}
$Speak = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVoice
$Speak.Voice = $Speak.GetVoices().Item($voice)
$Speak.Speak("$text") |Out-Null
```